# C++ Module: subcommand fails

Tags: c++, c++20, clion, c++-modules

I'm testing out modules in C++ but I keep getting the following errors:

`linker input file unused because linking not done`

and

```
ld: file not found: CMakeFiles/TestModule.dir/src/A.cppm.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Here is the following code that I have written:

The module: A.cppm

```cpp
export module A;

export namespace Lib_A {

    int getNumberOne() { return 1; }
    int getNumberTwo() { return 2; }

}
```

my main.cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
import A;

int main() {

    using namespace Lib_A;

    std::cout << getNumberOne() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getNumberTwo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And now my CMakeFile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(TestModule)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(TestModule src/main.cpp src/A.cppm)
```

I am using CLion btw and having looked at their documentation on module support I still cant seem to figure out what the issue might be.

I also added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")` in my CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake file as that was something that was suggested I should do; however, this did not solve the issue.

I am fairly new to C++; was hoping someone could help me out.  Thank you for your time!!

Comment: "*I am fairly new to C++;*" Are you sure you want to be using modules in Clang and CMake then? Support for modules in both of those is far from mature and is exceedingly fiddly. For the time being, if you want robust modules support, switch to Visual Studio. If you are unable or unwilling to do so, then it's probably best to wait until module support is more robust in Clang and CMake.

Comment: I mean even [CLion 2022.3 release page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2022/10/clion-2022-3-eap-cpp20-modules-now-supported/) claims they work to the extent in which [CMake supports them](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18355). Bugs happen I guess?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue today.  Solution was to change the `.cppm` extension to `.cpp.`

There are a number of file extensions that CMake recognizes as C++.  These are defined in `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`.  `cppm` is included in this list, at least for CMake version 3.25.1, so I am not sure why changing the extension to `.cpp` fixes the issue.  Maybe someone else knows.  This may be a bug given how new C++ modules are.